# How to use variables containing numbers in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have this as my code:

```
motifSearch = ''
intMin = 15
intMax = 21
intlen = intMax - intMin
SD = "TTGACA"
PBN = "TATAAT"

fastaFile = open('testseq.fsa', 'r')
for line in fastaFile:
    if deviation == 0:
        motSearch = re.search(SD+'([A-Z|a-z]){'+intMin,intMax+'}('+PBN+')', line)
        if motSearch is not None:
            motifSearch = motSearch.group(0)
print(motifSearch)
```

I have to find a first signal that is SD, then jump {intMin,intMax} number of characters, and then find the second signal PBN. When I print this out I get: "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly". 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Use string formatting.

```
regex = '{}([A-Z|a-z]){{},{}}({})'.format(SD, intMin, intMax, PBN)

motSearch = re.search(regex, line)
```

If your reusing variables or want something more readable you can also specify order this way...

```
regex = '{0}([A-Z|a-z]){{1},{2}}({3})'.format(SD, intMin, intMax, PBN)
```

Another example of string formatting to address string formatting issues (not sure how to get around the case of of using {} as you cannot escape them)

```
regex = '%s([A-Z|a-z]){%s,%s}(%s)' % (SD, intMin, intMax, PBN)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your last solution.
Now it complains about "Single '}' encountered in format string", but my code is:
motSearch = re.search("{0}([A-Z|a-z]){{1},{2}}({3})".format(SD, intMin, intMax, PBN)
But there is no single }, so do you have any idea of why it says so? -Maybe a simple question, but I am very new in programming.

Comment: See edit. That will resolve the error in the Python interpreter you are having. Not sure if the other method of string formatting will work but the updated version does for me.